# Spring Security Plugin Authentication Failure Issue

Tags: grails, spring-security

EDITED HEADER: more related with the actual problem

I'm trying to setup spring security for my test application

i installed the plugin , created User and Role classes ;

put this to UrlMappings.groovy;

```
        "/login/$action?"(controller: "login")
    "/logout/$action?"(controller: "logout")
```

then I put a user in the bootstrap as follows,

```
import org.project.auth.Role
import org.project.auth.User
import org.project.auth.UserRole;

class BootStrap {
    def springSecurityService
    def init = { servletContext ->
        def userRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError: true,flush:true)
        def adminRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(failOnError: true,flush:true)

        def adminUser = User.findByUsername('admin') ?: new User(

                username: 'admin',

                password: springSecurityService.encodePassword('admin'),

                enabled: true).save(failOnError: true,flush:true)

        print User.count()          

        if (!adminUser.authorities.contains(adminRole)) {
                    print "TEST"
            UserRole.create adminUser, adminRole,true
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

this print User.count() returns 1 so i know the user is created , print "TEST" works as well so i know that it goes into the if block but when i run the server it fails with

```
Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password.
```

I use Grails 2.0.0.M1 , do you think it might be the issue?

Comment: Where did you copy this code from? I feel like I've fixed this exact bug 2 or 3 times already, so I'd like to just copy/paste the previous answers :)

Comment: Also, what version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: hello Burt, i actually followed http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/ this tutorial

Comment: and the plug-in version is "plugins.spring-security-core=1.2"

Comment: Ok, but why the url mappings? Those are completely unnecessary.

Comment: well i thought so but since it was in the tutorial and i got an error i thought it might be the case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The User domain class in the 1.2 version of the plugin encrypts the password for you. So older code like this that uses the `springSecurityService` double-encodes. Change `password: springSecurityService.encodePassword('admin')` to `password: 'admin'` and it should work.

If not, turn up the debugging and you should see a message about why it's failing. Add this to Config.groovy in the log4j block:

```
debug 'org.springframework.security'
```

Also to be safe I'd change
`if (!adminUser.authorities.contains(adminRole)) {` to `if (!UserRole.findByUserAndRole(adminUser, adminRole)) {`
`

Answer (score 0):

I ma facing the same problem but after some searching came across this. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYUI-33
and http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYUI-27
Hope this helps. But i am unable to find the next stable version where this problem is fixed.